# Question regarding probability of distance between any two points in a given interval.

Tags: probability, statistics

How to solve following question:

Consider the interval $(0, 2)$ where two points are independently chosen at random. Find the probability that the distance between them is less than a fixed number $k$,where $k\in(0,2)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are any two points from the given interval, all I know is that I have to find $P(|X-Y|<k)$ and  the joint
distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform over the square of length side 2. But no idea how to choose numbers from an interval and proceed further. Kindly help.

Comment: find the area of the subset of $(0,2)\times(0,2)$ lying between the lines $y=x-k$ and $y=x+k$. After that divide by $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb R\to\{0,1\}$ is the indicator funtion of set $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid |x-y|<k\}$ then you are looking for:$$\Pr(|X-Y|<k)=\frac14\int_0^2\int_0^2f(x,y)dxdy$$
Try to calculate it yourself.
It is handsome though to make a picture here (see my comment on your question).